# How to start vim from go?

Tags: macos, vim, process, go, system

I've got a command line tool written in Golang and I need to start vim from it. However it's not working, and there's not any error or much else to work with. I've reduced the code to just this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("vim", "test.txt")
    err := cmd.Run()
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

When I run this, I can see the vim process for a 2-3 seconds but the application doesn't actually open. Then the program simply exits (and the vim process closes) with an "exit status 1".

I've also tried this to capture stderr:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("vim", "test.txt")
    var stderr bytes.Buffer
    cmd.Stderr = &stderr
    err := cmd.Run()
    fmt.Println(err)
    fmt.Println(stderr)
}
```

But in this case, the program gets stuck indefinitely.

Any idea what could be the issue?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Pass on `stdin` and `stdout` from the calling program which, provided it was run from a terminal (likely for a command line program) will start vim for you and return control when the user has finished editing the file.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("vim", "test.txt")
    cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    err := cmd.Run()
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

Comment: Wanted to run vimdiff from go. Thought I'd need to mess with a pty but no. It was this easy. Thanks for the clean example.

Answer (score 7):

VIM needs a proper terminal and detects the absence of one.

If you use the [`StderrPipe`](http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.StderrPipe) and read it while vim is running you will see this:

```
2014/02/02 20:25:49 Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal
2014/02/02 20:25:49 Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
```

Example for reading stderr while executing ([on play](http://play.golang.org/p/TlLpI5eW7l)):

```
func logger(pipe io.ReadCloser) {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(pipe)

    for {
        output, err := reader.ReadString('\n')

        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            return
        }

        log.Print(string(output))
    }
}

pipe, err := cmd.StderrPipe()

go logger(pipe)
cmd.Run()
```

For vim to run you probably need to emulate a terminal.

Maybe [goat](https://github.com/kylelemons/goat/) ([doc](http://godoc.org/github.com/kylelemons/goat/term)) can help you out:

```
tty := term.NewTTY(os.Stdin)

cmd := exec.Command("vim", "test.txt")
cmd.Stdin = t
cmd.Stdout = t

// ...
```